# Why does bash -c "ulimit -Sn" have different output when called from a JVM?

Tags: java, shell

The command is "ulimit -Sn" and the Java code which calling it like following

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c", cmd });
process.waitFor();
BufferedReader outputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line = "";

while ((line = outputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line + "\n");
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
```

I run the command in shell the result is 1024, but in the same shell run java code the result is 4096. why?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `ulimit`? This has nothing to do with Java and everything to do with *the command returning different output*.

Comment: BTW You should consume the process's output *before* calling `waitFor()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It's completely normal for different processes to have different ulimits configured; this has nothing to do with java or bash.

You're asking for the soft limit on maximum number of open file descriptors configured for your process.

Again: **Configured for your process**. Different processes can have different ulimits configured.

If one of these is started from a systemd service, for example, `LimitNOFILE=4096` would provide a new value.

If one of them is started from a script that calls the `ulimit` command, *that* could provide a new value.

If one of them is started by a user account or a service or a login mechanism with PAM rules configured, *that too* could provide a new value.

---

On Linux, by the way, you can extract this value in a completely language-independent way by reading the file `/proc/self/limits`. By substituting in the PID of a different process in place of `self`, you can read and compare this across different processes.

Comment: But the two ways I ran are in the same shell. First I run 'ulimit -Sn' directly then run java code. Since in the same shell, I think the environment (etc. PAM) is identical. If the limit can be different in the same shell, where and how it decided?

Comment: It's a per-process flag -- any process can change it. Your shell starts a JVM -> that's a new process, it has the ability if it chooses to change its own ulimit and that of its children. That JVM starts a second shell -> that shell inherits the ulimit set by the JVM. You can find the PID of your JVM and inspect `/proc/${jvm_pid}/limits` if you want to confirm this.